# An ordered has_many association in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many

I think it's not an uncommon requirement, but I can't find a proper solution.

I have a recipe model with a n:1 Relation to instructions.

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :instructions, autosave: true, class_name: 'RecipeInstruction'
end
```

No I want to order the instructions in a recipe by hand. So my first approach was to add a position attribute to instructions and add the following.

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :instructions, -> { order('position ASC') }, autosave: true, class_name: 'RecipeInstruction'
end
```

I set the position attribute in the recipe controller. There are two disadvantages with this solution:

1. I have to set the position attribute of the instructions everywhere, where I create instructions.
2. The order statement only affects fetches from the db. When I change the position attribute in not persisted recipes/instructions, it does not affect the order.

In other programming languages I would override getter and setter of this relation. Which Operators of the association I have to override to cover all possibilities of adding an object to the relation?

PS: I do know that I can override the << operator of the association with:

```
has_many :instructions, -> { order('position ASC') }, autosave: true, class_name: 'RecipeInstruction' do
    def << *args
    end
end
```

But the = Operator can't be overwritten this way, can it?

Edit: Now I know how to override the = Operator. Do I have to override all possibilities or is there a method that is called by every operator to add an instruction, like push?
And how can I force a "reload" of the related objects when I change the position attribute of one or more instructions?

PPS: Overriding the setter for instructions
I tried both variants, but none was called by rails after submitting the form. But the instructions where assigned to the recipe. So there must be another option so set it/to override the setter:

```
has_many :instructions, -> { order('position ASC') }, autosave: true, class_name: 'RecipeInstruction' do
    def instructions=(instructions)
        raise error
    end
end

has_many :instructions, -> { order('position ASC') }, autosave: true, class_name: 'RecipeInstruction'

def instructions=(instructions)
        raise error
end
```

PPPS: Solution for setting the position

The first step is taken. I think this is a good solution for initializing the position attribute:

```
has_many :instructions, -> { order('position ASC') }, autosave: true, class_name: 'RecipeInstruction', before_add: :initialize_instruction


def initialize_instruction(instruction)
    instruction.position = instructions.length
end
```

Comment: Interesting question. Have you considered changing your pattern so that `position` is not manual, but handled by some logic, either manual or from a gem?

Comment: That is what I am considering now. I would like to set the position attribute in the recipe model.

Comment: How would you define the position from recipe? How would it relate to the other positions?

Comment: An instruction does only belong to one recipe. So when I set instructions, I iterate over the instructions and set the position attribute of every instruction to the index.

Comment: Alright, so the `position` has a definite scope to `recipe_id`. So when you save a `recipe`, we know the `recipe` of the `instruction`, hence you want to set its position. Do you have context for this? How is it being used? Restaurant?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. But not only on save. Just on the fly. So I have to 'reset' the getter for instructions after each position change. There is no more context. Just a recipe containing instructions I want to order.

Comment: I'll write an answer but I doubt it will work, it may give you ideas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102829/discussion-between-rich-peck-and-noeden).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the answer already; to give something which *may* help, you have access to the [`proxy_association`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions) objects when you extend the `has_many` association:

```
has_many :instructions, -> { order('position ASC') }, autosave: true, class_name: 'RecipeInstruction' do
    def x
       proxy_association.target
    end
end
```

According to these [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Association+extensions), you'll also get access to `record.association(:name)` objects:

```
@recipe = Recipe.find x
@recipe.instructions = @recipe.association(:instructions).target #-> returns collection of instructions
```

This will give you access to an array of the instructions, from which you'll be able to extract the `positions`:

```
@positions = @recipe.association(:instructions).target.select { |k,v| key.to_s.match(/^position\d+/) }
```

---

There's also a [`reload`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-reload) method:

```
person.pets.reload # fetches pets from the database
# => [#<Pet id: 1, name: "Snoop", group: "dogs", person_id: 1>]
```

---

Sadly, I don't have anything for interjecting into the `<<` / `.destroy` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all your help. I finally found a good solution:

https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list

It is a plugin which solves the problem very well.

Edit: But only for persisted records. I assume that is 'active record style'.

Answer (score 0):

You can write getters/setters in Rails. For example, to write a getter and setter for your Recipe object (in your model),

```
def position
  where('some req').order('some way')
end

def position=(arg1)
  self.something = arg1
end
```

That's how you override the `=` operator.

Comment: Thanks, but which operators/setters do I have to override to cover all possibilities?

Comment: You should need to override only the above two operators for all the cases (since you'd probably get or set the attribute, it can't be deleted per se).

Comment: No, it does not work for me. I added my code in my question.